Count Total Records Per Minute in a 3-Node NiFi Cluster with Load Balancer
I'm working with a 3-node NiFi cluster behind a Load Balancer that distributes data equally across the nodes. I need to track the total number of records processed by the cluster within a one-minute timeframe.
Desired outcome :
Calculate the total number of records processed by the entire cluster (all 3 nodes combined) in a single minute.
Current Flow :
haldleHttpRequest --> MergeRecord (bin age is 1 min) --> calculateRecordStats (to get count)
But my current flow is counting the number of records received by a node in a min not the total number of received data in a cluster in 1 min. Please suggest.
